# What is the left button(Q) on bottom bar for?

Tags: support, design, ios-app

What is the left button(Q) on the bottom bar for? It doesn't respond to touches. Confusing.

[image]

Initially I though it was a toolbar. But as @Kevin pointed out in his answer, it is a tab bar. So it is actually a bad design instead of a buggy button. Only worse. So I suggest a re-design. Using a tab button to present a modal composer view just doesn't make any sense. And the left button is useless and confusing. I can see that you've used up both left and right buttons on navigation bar but you still want a composer button. A toolbar just for one composer button is wasteful. A floating composer button seems a proper way to go.

Comment: It looks like an "ask a new question" button.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Except it is not. The right one is.

Comment: @RobertHarvey The one on the right asks a new question, and this *is* a list of questions. So none of those work.

Comment: The one on the right looks like a "New balloon" button.

Comment: I think the one on the right is kind of like a like button, except it means "I'm thinking about addition."

Answer (score 3):

That's a tab bar; the Q balloon is the active tab ("view existing questions").  Since it's already active, nothing will happen when you tap on it. Tapping on + will bring you to a different view (normally within the tab controller, apparently this pops up a modal), and from there tapping Q will bring you back to the question list.

Comment: As an iOS dev, I hereby state that this is a really weird design pattern. You simply aren't supposed to show a modal when a tab button is pressed.

Comment: I'm an iOS dev too, I just haven't used the app yet. Does it really pop up a modal? I agree that's not great design. Or at least not consistent with established iOS practices.

Comment: Yeah, asking a new question shows a modal. And there isn't a tab bar at the bottom of it, either.

Comment: I should have noticed the height of the bottom bar to see it is not a toolbar. It is really a bad design. And I don't see Q in the presented modal view.

Comment: @an0 Yeah, that's because (like Undo said), it pops up a modal. If it didn't, you'd see the same bar, with the + highlighted instead.

Answer (score 2):

Honestly, the tab bar could just be removed entirely.

On the main site, asking a question is a button off to the side from all the other buttons. On the app, there's a button on the sidebar. That seems the most consistent (so long as they fix [the site bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/221302/ask-question-from-sidebar-picks-wrong-site)). It seems unproductive to include it on the bottom bar, wasting a bunch of usable pixels next to it.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe the following screenshot (from version **0.1.22**, which will release tonight) will clarify what the button is for:

[image]

If you happen to find yourself on the tags screen now, the [Q - Questions], button helps you go back to the question listing.

Comment: The main issue is that you misuse the right tab bar item as a normal button to present a modal composer view. Tab bar is for tab switching. It is a very strange and bad design. If you are in doubt, please invite iOS developers from SO to vote.