# "Ask Question" from Sidebar Picks Wrong Site

Tags: bug, status-completed, asking-questions, ios-app

Tapping <kbd>Ask Question</kbd> from the sidebar in the iOS app begins composing from my highest-listed site, rather than the one I'm currently on.

An argument could be made that from the sidebar you aren't really on a site, but that could be intuitively remedied by highlighting the side site.

Comment: Just as a note: The question mark with a + instead of a "Q" in it on the bottom panel when looking at a site does what you expect.

Comment: Understood. There are other complaints about [that button](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/221033/248072) though. In fact I was trying to see if it's practicable to just remove that bar completely, and that's when I came across this issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll see this behavior in the next build.  If you're coming from the feed it will select your highest rep site.  If you're coming from a site, it will choose that site.

Comment: Just your highest rep site.  There's also a condition where if you have two sites with equal rep, nothing it leaves it blank.  That's unchanged (unless you are on a site).