# Tab bar is gone after viewing a user profile from search

Tags: bug, status-completed, ios-app

[image: Missing bottom tab bar]

Steps to reproduce:

1. Go to a site.
2. Tap "Users" in the bottom bar.
3. Scroll up to reveal the search bar.
4. Enter search term, hit search.
5. Tap to open any profile.
6. Go back.
7. Tap "Cancel" on search bar.

This is when I would expect the bottom tab bar to reappear, but it doesn't.

I have version 0.1.29 on iOS 7.1.

Comment: Oh sweet! You got rid of it! :P ([some people don't like it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/221031/what-is-the-left-buttonq-on-bottom-bar-for#comment717287_221033))

Comment: Have you tried shaking the phone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will be fixed in **version 0.1.30**