# Tab bar is gone after tapping on tag in Tags tab then swiping back

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags, ios-app

**Description:**

The tab bar on the bottom disappeared after tapping on a tag in the Tags tab then swiping back.

**Steps to reproduce:**

1. Open the left drawer, then tap Stack Overflow to go to the Stack Overflow site.
2. On the tab bar on the bottom, tap **Tags**.
3. In the Tags tab, tap any tag.
4. In the search result page, swipe from the left edge to go back.
5. Now the tap bar is gone.

**Actual Results:**

There should be a tab bar on the bottom.

**Expected Results:**

The tab bar on the bottom is missing.

**Environment:**

- Stack Exchange iOS App v0.1.30
- iPhone 5
- iOS 7.1

**Screenshots:**

[image: Go to Tags, then tap a tag] → [image: Tag search result] → [image: Swipe from left edge to go back] → [image: Tab bar gone]

**Note:**

1. There is no such problem if I go back by tapping on Cancel instead of swiping from the left edge.
2. Similar but different bug: [Tab bar is gone after viewing a user profile from search](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/226774/tab-bar-is-gone-after-viewing-a-user-profile-from-search)

Comment: Confirmed. It'd sure be nice if the tab bar could always be there, *even in search*

Comment: @mhlester Or make it hide on scroll down a'la Safari.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will be **fixed in 0.1.44.**

Comment: Verified fixed in 0.1.44 (there seems to be no 0.1.31).