# Non-modal question dialog in app

Tags: feature-request, asking-questions, ios-app

Forked from this request: [Don't go modal in app search](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228682)
Related support/discussion: [What is the left button(Q) on bottom bar for?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/221031/what-is-the-left-buttonq-on-bottom-bar-for)

When selecting the Ask tab from the tab bar, a modal window is brought up. Read the related question for some harsh words on the approach.

First, you can't see the tab bar because there's a keyboard. The solution to that is to let me hide the keyboard through the same mechanism used in Messages, Mail, etc. As a side-effect of scrolling, you effectively drag the keyboard off screen.

Second, now that the keyboard is out of the way, actually show said tab bar.

> [image: non-modal ask]

Rounding out the trifecta, but it was requested this be a different post, lose the <kbd>Cancel</kbd> button and bring back access to the sidebar. That post is here: