# Let me access the sidebar from asking in app

Tags: feature-request, asking-questions, ios-app

Potentially dependent on this related request: [Non-modal question dialog in app](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228832)
Forked from this request: [Don't go modal in app search](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228682/)

It was asked that I make this a separate post.

Instead of the <kbd>Cancel</kbd> button in the top-left, put the sidebar button back. As part of that, swiping from the left edge should work as well.

> [image: sidebar restored]

Comment: MORE FEATURE REQUESTS!  IMMEDIATELY!

Comment: I'm SO SORRY! Ben Collins asked me to split one post up. I felt so embarrassed spamming the front page like this I actually blushed at my desk

Comment: MOOOOOOAAAAAR!!  I FEED ON THEM!

Comment: What do you expect to happen if you select a new site in the picker?

Comment: @Brian, save my draft, switch to Questions tab (for the new site of course). It would be the same action as if I were on any other tab.

Comment: Sorry, I meant via the little button (next to question title).

Comment: Oooh, good point @Brian! With a non-modal view, you would theoretically be able to have a different draft for different sites. That icon would then, uh, well, maybe go away?